# PHPMailer sin la configuración SMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo un formulario de contacto y me di cuenta que los correos no llegaban y era porque el hosting tiene desactivada la función `@mail` y me dijeron que usara `PHPMailer`.

Solamente que tengo el problema de que no sabemos los datos de configuración del servidor `SMTP`, existe alguna forma de poder usar `PHPMailer` sin esos datos?

```
<?php 
require("class.phpmailer.php");

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
$email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
$subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
$contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));


// Load Composer's autoloader


// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions


try {
 //Server settings
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
 $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
 $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
 $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
 $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to


    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('luribe@qvoz.com', 'Luis Uribe');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);     // Add a recipient


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format 
 to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $contact_message;
    $mail->AltBody = $contact_message;

    $mail->send();
   echo "Mensaje enviado";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

Este es mi código de `phpMailer`.

Comment: Prueba el puerto 465 si es SSL. También puedes probar el puerto 25 sin SSL (aunque no recomendado).

Comment: por hacer un simil, podriamos decir que es como si quisieras conectar a una bbdd, pero no tuvieras los datos de conexion. Si no tienes los datos de un servidor de envio de correo SMTP, no vas a poder enviar correos. Te sugiero que contactes con el proveedor de tu alojamiento, por si te ofrece un SMTP. En caso de no poder contactar, puedes buscar otros servicios publicos, como gmail, sendgrid..., crearte una cuenta y configurarla en tu phpmailer

Comment: 1) Si el servidor te da cuentas de correo lo normal es que tengan un acceso pop y smtp, y el hosting te da esos datos de configuración. 2) Si el hosting es tan malo que no te provee eso, podes usar una cuenta externa por ejemplo de gmail y la configuras con los datos que te da gmail.

Comment: @juan Si tenemos un hosting pero me comentan que esos correos los tiene como vinculados a la G suite Academy de google

Comment: Si te han dado un correo que podes usar de G Suite, seguramente se configura con el smpt de gmail. De otro modo crea una cuenta en gmail y usa esa. Aca tenes de donde sacar los datos de configuración. https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=es

Comment: @Juan si ya me dieron las configuraciones necesarias, pero ahora me manda este error. Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.  dice que el usuario y contraseña no son aceptados, y  el usuario y contraseña son correctos es la cuenta de google que usan

Comment: Fijate que SMTPMail tiene un atributo de debug que lleva un nivel. Seteale el debug y luefo fijate en el archivo de log el paso a paso que hace para ver donde falla. En todo caso agrega el log a la pregunta (fijate que no haya passwords en el texto)

Comment: @Juan ya pude corregir el error que me marcaba , tenia que hacer unas configuraciones mas en el gmail, ya me marca que el correo fue enviado pero no me llega el correo tampoco en la bandeja de SMAP

Comment: Te fijaste en spam

Comment: @Juan Ya lo pude resolver, tenia al revez 2 lineas, en vez de llegar al correo, le llegaba al correo que pusieron en el formulario, pero ya pude corregirlo. Gracias por tu ayuda